# Brindy Vaadin OSGi/ Guessit -Felix works, Equinox does Not

Tags: osgi, vaadin, bndtools

Using bndtools 2.0 and creating project as per [latest Brindy Github version](https://github.com/brindy/VaadinOSGi), Vaadin starts up and all works well when I create run bnd that pulls in dependencies based on felix http jetty and felix scr.

But if I try to run with org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty etc. the servlet does not seem to be registered and vaadin fails to start.

When debugging into the code all of the ds component factory bits work OK but the servlet does not recognise the alias.

I am trying to get this to run before attempting to alter it for vaadin 7.

Any suggestions where the problem might be?

Comment: You might want to include links to what you're referring to and also any sample code if you can.

Comment: a) What does the log say?

Comment: @peter Brindy code does not have any logging running, but the system running  with equinox fails to start Vaadin (quietly), without any exceptions. I will do some logging and try and isolate the problem area. If you are referring to a bndtools log..where is it to be found?

Comment: I've only tested this on Felix (should be safe to assume it works on other containers, right? ;)  - I will give it a shot later today (if I get time).

Comment: It seems totally broken with bndtools 2.0 - what did you do to fix it?  Feel free to make a pull request and then I can test it out with Equinox.

Comment: bnd(tools) has no logging, it uses the OSGi log. Best is to install WebConsole. Easiest is to create a bndrun file and select the webconsole profile. Look at localhost:8080/system/console (user:pw admin:admin), there is a log tab.

Comment: @brindy I created a new bndtools project. Copied src into project and created sub bundles to match your github project. I created a run descriptor to use Equinox with console and resolve pulled in the felix bundles that for me worked. When I tried to use equinox bundles it resolved but did not work !!

Comment: @PeterKriens The option to use webconsole seems to be only for Felix. Felix is working for me.. I am using equinox with console which is of no help except to show it is not starting up vaadin.

Comment: You can add all the felix bundles also to an equinox framework, the beauty of OSGi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now working..I had not entered org.eclipse.equinox.cm as a dependency.

Using these bundles provided the working result, with just one problem.

org.apache.felix.webconsole resulted in error

2013-02-12 12:20:14.441:WARN:/:ERROR:  org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.servlet.OsgiManager: Failed to instantiate plugin org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.deppack.DepPackServlet

Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.osgi.service.deploymentadmin.DeploymentException

```
id  State       Bundle
0   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.2.v20120110-1415
1   ACTIVE      com.vaadin_6.8.0
2   ACTIVE      javax.servlet_3.0.0.v201112011016
3   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.cm_1.0.400.v20120522-1841
4   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.0.v20120522-1841
5   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_3.0.0.v20120522-1841
6   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet_1.1.300.v20120522-1841
7   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.util_1.0.300.v20110502
8   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.continuation_8.1.3.v20120522
9   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.http_8.1.3.v20120522
10  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.io_8.1.3.v20120522
11  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.security_8.1.3.v20120522
12  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.server_8.1.3.v20120522
13  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_8.1.3.v20120522
14  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.util_8.1.3.v20120522
15  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.3.100.v20120522-1822
16  ACTIVE      org.vaadin.osgi_0.0.0
17  ACTIVE      org.vaadin.osgi.staticres_0.0.0
18  ACTIVE      org.vaadin.guessit_0.0.0
19  ACTIVE      org.vaadin.guessit-support_0.0.0
20  ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.webconsole_3.1.8
```

Comment: I had seen this sill CFNE org.osgi.service.deploymentadmin.DeploymentException. This dependency should not exist (or at least be optional), I report this as an error at Apache Felix.

Comment: Update: It is already handled according to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX-3099